# Python imbalanced-learn: How does the BalancedBaggingClassifier 'ratio' argument work?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

**Introduction**

I am working on a binary classification task with very imbalanced datasets (~1000 instances of class 1, ~10000000 instances of class 0) and am experimenting with the [imbalanced-learn](http://contrib.scikit-learn.org/imbalanced-learn/stable/index.html) library to create balanced samples for the classification algorithms.

My idea was to use bagging to create several classifiers trained on balanced samples from the dataset. The imbalanced-learn library offers the [BalancedBaggingClassifier](http://contrib.scikit-learn.org/imbalanced-learn/stable/generated/imblearn.ensemble.BalancedBaggingClassifier.html#imblearn.ensemble.BalancedBaggingClassifier) method that is otherwise similar to the BaggingClassifier in scikit-learn but should automatically create balanced samples of the input data.

BalancedBaggingClassifier has the parameter 'ratio' that should control how the data is sampled for the bagged classifiers:

> ratio : str, dict, or callable, optional (default=’auto’)
>
> Ratio to use for resampling the data set.
>
> If str, has to be one of: (i) 'minority': resample the minority class;
>   (ii) 'majority': resample the majority class, (iii) 'not minority':
>   resample all classes apart of the minority class, (iv) 'all': resample
>   all classes, and (v) 'auto': correspond to 'all' with for
>   over-sampling methods and 'not minority' for under-sampling methods.
>   The classes targeted will be over-sampled or under-sampled to achieve
>   an equal number of sample with the majority or minority class.
>           If dict, the keys correspond to the targeted classes. The values correspond to the desired number of samples.
>           If callable, function taking y and returns a dict. The keys correspond to the targeted classes. The values correspond to the
>   desired number of samples.

My interpretation for this was that let us say I would like to create a sample  with 1000 instances from class 1 and 1000 instances of class 0, I would set ratio = 'majority' and then class 1 would not be sampled but for class 0 I would get a new sample for each of the bagged classifiers. However this is not how it seems to work. Instead regardless of how I set the parameters 'ratio' and 'max_samples' it seems to me that all classes are always sampled and that the resulting sample is not balanced with regard to the class labels.

**Minimal working example**

Below I have tried to make a minimal working example:

```
import numpy as np

from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from imblearn.ensemble import BalancedBaggingClassifier
from sklearn import preprocessing
from imblearn.under_sampling import RandomUnderSampler

#dataset size
N_features = 1
N_samples_0 = 20
N_samples_1 = 10

X = np.zeros(shape=(N_samples_0+N_samples_1,N_features))
y = np.zeros(shape=(N_samples_0+N_samples_1,1))

#parameters for classifier
n_estimators = 1
max_samples = 1.0
ratio = 'majority'
replacement = False
n_jobs = 1
seed = 123

#initialise classifiers
model = BalancedBaggingClassifier(base_estimator=LogisticRegression(penalty='l2',tol=0.01,class_weight='balanced',verbose=1,n_jobs=1),n_estimators=n_estimators, max_samples=max_samples, ratio=ratio, replacement=replacement, n_jobs=n_jobs,verbose=1000, random_state=seed)

print model

#create imbalanced training set
mus_0 = [0+i for i in range(0,N_features)]
sigmas_0 = [0.5 for i in range(0,N_features)]
mus_1 = [max(mus_0)+1+i for i in range(0,N_features)]
sigmas_1 = [0.1+i for i in range(0,N_features)]

#class 0
for i in range(0,N_features):
    X[:N_samples_0,i] = np.random.normal(loc=mus_0[i],scale=sigmas_0[i],size=(N_samples_0))

#class 1
for i in range(0,N_features):
    X[N_samples_0:,i] = np.random.normal(loc=mus_1[i],scale=sigmas_1[i],size=(N_samples_1))
y[N_samples_0:,:] = 1

print "original data:"
for i in range(0,N_samples_0+N_samples_1):
    print X[i,:],
    print y[i]

#scaling and fitting
scaler = preprocessing.StandardScaler().fit(X)

model.fit(scaler.transform(X),y.ravel())

for array in model.estimators_samples_:
    print "sample that should be balanced:"
    X_sample = X[array]
    y_sample = y[array.ravel()]
    for i in range(0,X_sample.shape[0]):
        print X_sample[i,:],
        print y_sample[i]
    print "sample size="+str(X_sample.shape[0])
```

Which creates the following output:

```
BalancedBaggingClassifier(base_estimator=LogisticRegression(C=1.0, class_weight='balanced', dual=False,
          fit_intercept=True, intercept_scaling=1, max_iter=100,
          multi_class='ovr', n_jobs=1, penalty='l2', random_state=None,
          solver='liblinear', tol=0.01, verbose=1, warm_start=False),
             bootstrap=True, bootstrap_features=False, max_features=1.0,
             max_samples=1.0, n_estimators=1, n_jobs=1, oob_score=False,
             random_state=123, ratio='majority', replacement=False,
             verbose=1000, warm_start=False)
original data:
[ 0.40428533] [ 0.]
[-0.33618956] [ 0.]
[ 0.21882232] [ 0.]
[ 0.12895395] [ 0.]
[ 0.19926973] [ 0.]
[ 0.31555022] [ 0.]
[-0.6319698] [ 0.]
[-0.3728038] [ 0.]
[-0.4149535] [ 0.]
[-0.50807259] [ 0.]
[ 0.23080791] [ 0.]
[-0.39007103] [ 0.]
[-0.78354529] [ 0.]
[-0.49436092] [ 0.]
[-0.5353324] [ 0.]
[ 0.64506565] [ 0.]
[-0.15218196] [ 0.]
[ 0.30436546] [ 0.]
[-0.26640216] [ 0.]
[ 1.06123697] [ 0.]
[ 0.90361633] [ 1.]
[ 0.96685144] [ 1.]
[ 0.82633085] [ 1.]
[ 1.01901688] [ 1.]
[ 1.01441932] [ 1.]
[ 1.09587832] [ 1.]
[ 0.88554739] [ 1.]
[ 0.94325122] [ 1.]
[ 0.99280218] [ 1.]
[ 0.96425554] [ 1.]
Building estimator 1 of 1 for this parallel run (total 1)...
[LibLinear]iter  1 act 7.788e+00 pre 7.105e+00 delta 1.821e+00 f 1.525e+01 |g| 8.874e+00 CG   2
iter  2 act 3.941e-01 pre 3.682e-01 delta 1.821e+00 f 7.461e+00 |g| 1.482e+00 CG   2
iter  3 act 4.836e-03 pre 4.797e-03 delta 1.821e+00 f 7.067e+00 |g| 1.506e-01 CG   2
[Parallel(n_jobs=1)]: Done   1 out of   1 | elapsed:    0.0s remaining:    0.0s
[Parallel(n_jobs=1)]: Done   1 out of   1 | elapsed:    0.0s finished
sample that should be balanced:
[ 0.40428533] [ 0.]
[-0.33618956] [ 0.]
[ 0.21882232] [ 0.]
[ 0.19926973] [ 0.]
[-0.6319698] [ 0.]
[-0.50807259] [ 0.]
[ 0.23080791] [ 0.]
[-0.39007103] [ 0.]
[ 0.64506565] [ 0.]
[-0.15218196] [ 0.]
[ 0.30436546] [ 0.]
[ 0.96685144] [ 1.]
[ 0.82633085] [ 1.]
[ 1.01441932] [ 1.]
[ 1.09587832] [ 1.]
[ 0.88554739] [ 1.]
[ 0.99280218] [ 1.]
[ 0.96425554] [ 1.]
sample size=18
```

So unless I have made some stupid mistake the classes seem not to be balanced. And on top of that both classes seem to be sampled although I set ratio='majority'. When working with my own dataset that has much larger imbalance my code crashes because BalancedBaggingClassifier creates samples that only have instances from the majority class.

**Specific question**

How to parametrise the BalancedBaggingClassifier so that it would create balanced samples (with this I mean that there would be at least approximately the same number of instances from both classes 0 and 1 in the sample)?

**Bonus question**

From the description of the 'ratio' parameter I interpret that BalancedBaggingClassifier could be used to undersample one class and oversample the other. However from the source code I can only gather that it uses the [RandomUnderSampler](http://contrib.scikit-learn.org/imbalanced-learn/stable/generated/imblearn.under_sampling.RandomUnderSampler.html#imblearn.under_sampling.RandomUnderSampler). Can I do both over and undersampling or have I misunderstood the documentation?